# Cocoapods import development pod into Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a development pod which contains Objective C code. I would like to import this into my Swift project. Previously, I just added the header files to the Bridging Header file and everything worked fine. Now I'd like to use the `use_frameworks!` flag to build the development pod as a dynamic framework.

When I do this, there are errors in the Xcode project.

```
Use of unresolved identifier...
```

However, when I control click the class name in Xcode, it correctly takes me to the source file.

My question is - when I have a development pod that uses Objective C and I add this to a Swift project using the `use_frameworks!` flag, how do I import my files into the Swift code? Do I need to create some kind of bridging header file or use any kind of import statement?

Comment: You still need the bridging header.

Comment: What would this import look like? I've tried multiple different syntax and each time it says "Could not build module..."

Comment: Just the normal import statements. For example: #import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>

Comment: I think you just want `import Pod` in the Swift code that needs it.